# Is this possible in controller test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, integration-testing

In my user controller I have a before_action for the new page/method. This before_action includes:

```
@organization = Organization.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

In my user fixtures I have an `organization: one` for user @admin, and in my organizations fixtures I have a record for this organization "one". Still my controller test fails on the above line with the message:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Organization without an ID

Why is this? Is it not possible to do this in a controller test and should I use an integration test instead? If I can use a controller test (which I here prefer), what is wrong with my code?

---

The controller test:

```
  test "should get new" do
    log_in_as("user", @admin) # Test helper that functions properly
    get :new                  # It fails here on the before_action defined in the users controller.
    assert_response :success
  end
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `before_action` be `@organisation = @admin.organisation` based on what you've explained?

Comment: It's just one line from the `before_action`. @admin in a variable in the test file, while the before_action exists in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You expect to have `params[:id]`, and you don't pass it. Try

```
test "should get new" do
  log_in_as("user", @admin)
  get :new, id: 1 # or any other
  assert_response :success
end
```

You either need to change your `before_action` filter or update your tests.

Comment: Yes, this worked. Included the organization in the `setup` of the test and passed the id.

Answer (score 0):

As the information you showed, i think the problem is you should limit the before action.
For example 
`before_action :set_organization, except:[:index,:new]` or use only
`before_action :set_organization, only:[:show,:edit,:update,:destroy]`.

If you want set organization for all actions, then you should provide the id params.

eg:

```
  before_action :set_organization

  def set_organization
     @organization = Organization.friendly.find(params[:organization_id])
  end


  get :new,organization_id: 1
```